# Figure caption line breaking after first letter

Tags: floats

For all of my figures I am getting a line break after the first letter, so for example my PDF looks like

```
Figure 1: V
arying negative h values are plotted
```

All of the text is centered because I am using `\centering`.
Here is the tex for one of the figures:

```
\subsection*{3}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{Capture2.PNG}
\begin{caption}
Varying negative h values are plotted
\end{caption}
\end{figure}
```

I have never seen this before, and am unsure of what I am doing differently. I see this behavior both on writelatex.com as well as when compiled locally.

Comment: Use `\caption{<content>}`

Comment: It's `\caption{Varying negative values}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

```
\begin{caption}
    <content>
\end{caption}
```

is inappropriate. Rather use the command `\caption{<content>}`. See the MWE below illustrating the effects.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{Capture2.PNG}
% The below use for the declaration of a caption is wrong
\begin{caption}
Varying negative h values are plotted
\end{caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{Capture2.PNG}
\caption{Varying negative h values are plotted} % correct
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forget to put brackets for your caption.
So if you write the caption like this `\caption`, it would break the line.
But if you write caption like `\caption{text}` it will fix.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!